# How can I see the percentages in Interact options?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-comes-alive

Sometimes, when Interacting with the villagers, the percentages next to the options that show which is the way to go, disappears. Why is this and how can I get the percentages to show again?